# NSString to wchar_t*?

Tags: string, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I can't seem to find a good built-in way to convert an NSString to wchar_t... any tips on how to do this? Anything Apple exposes on the NSString class is for c-strings (char*) or for unichars, but nothing for wchar*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[urString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding]
```

`wchar_t` is compiler specific. Assuming you wan the Win32 `wchar_t`, then UTF16 little ending encoded will do it. For Unix `wchar_t` you may need the NSUTF32 encoding family, with your platform of choice endianess.

Comment: Apple's doc for `-cStringUsingEncoding:` says: [*"UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not considered to be C string encodings, and should not be used with this method—the results of passing **NSUTF16StringEncoding**, NSUTF32StringEncoding, **or any of their variants** are undefined"*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstringusingencoding?language=objc). This answer seems wrong.

Comment: For example, `iOS` is based on Linux and uses ARM arch CPU (which is little-endian), so, to pass `NSString` to `C/C++` code use `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:   (not sure if this will be applicable for wchar_t as well)

```
NSString *pStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", GetTCHARString()];
```

Comment: There's nothing in the docs about `GetTCHARString` and it won't compile.