# How to convert NSString to/from TCHAR (using CLucene)

Tags: iphone, nsstring, wchar-t, clucene

I'm developing an application for iPhone, in which I've imported c++ `CLucene` library.
Almost all `CLucene` functiona require `String` as `TCHAR*`.

I've some problems in converting `NSString` to/from this type of data. I've searched many solution but none worked.

Can you please show me how to make this conversion?

I was able to make library work with test string defined `with _T()` macro. However XCode give me:

```
Conversion from string literal to 'TCHAR *' (aka 'wchar_t *') is deprecated.
```

Which is the non deprecated method to do it?

Thank you!

Edit:
I solved this way:

Converting from `NSString` to `TCHAR*`:

```
(const TCHAR *) [stringa cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

Converting from `TCHAR*` to `NSString`:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ctc length:wcslen(ctc) *  sizeof(TCHAR)  encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]
```

thank you!

Comment: You might want to look at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610871/how-to-copy-a-wchar-t-into-an-nsstring) and [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891594/nsstring-to-wchar-t).

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
NSString *pStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", GetTCHARString()];
```