# How to do NSString to cont wchar_t * conversion

Tags: objective-c

Following is my code where I've to make conversion

```
NSString *str = @"\path\abcd\" ; 

cont wchar_t * path = str;
```

Can I achieve this using mbsrtowcs?

Comment: This link may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753262/how-to-convert-wchar-t-to-nsstring

Comment: How can I use this for converting NSString to wchar_t?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891594/nsstring-to-wchar-t